# RabbitMQ Web Stomp -- Turn off non-TLS connections?

Tags: rabbitmq, web-stomp

I have a RabbitMQ instance (running the current 3.7.9 + Erlang 21.1.1) that is working great.

I use the Web Stomp plugin to make values available in the browser using websockets and stomp.js.  This is also working well.

My question is: how do I DISABLE the non-TLS connections using the new-format .conf files?  I want to make sure we don't connect accidentally to the wrong port.  Below is my .conf file for reference.

Current listening ports:

Protocol    Bound to    Port

amqp    ::  5672

amqp/ssl    ::  5671

clustering  ::  25672

**http/web-stomp    ::  15674**

https   ::  15672

https/web-stomp     ::  15671

stomp   ::  61613

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671
ssl_options.cacertfile = fullchain.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = privkey.pem
ssl_options.verify     = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false

management.listener.port = 15672
management.listener.ssl = true
management.listener.ssl_opts.cacertfile = fullchain.pem
management.listener.ssl_opts.certfile = cert.pem
management.listener.ssl_opts.keyfile = privkey.pem

web_stomp.ssl.port       = 15671
web_stomp.ssl.backlog    = 1024
web_stomp.ssl.certfile   = cert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.keyfile    = privkey.pem
web_stomp.ssl.cacertfile = fullchain.pem
```

The following links were VERY helpful, but I did not find an answer.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#peer-verification

https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version `3.7.9` there is no way to disable the HTTP listener. I suggest using the following setting to limit the listener to `localhost` only:

```
web_stomp.tcp.ip = 127.0.0.1
```

If you check the output of `netstat -pan | fgrep beam.smp` you will see port `15674` bound to a `localhost` listener.